# Azure FTP Issue - cannot upload files

Tags: azure, ftp

I cannot connect to my Azure Ftp account. i see the folder i try to upload files to, the site folder using FileZilla like i always do, but I see that most of the files fail to upload.
Does anybody else has similar issues?

Comment: You should really provide more information, like if you see any error messages from FileZilla.

Answer (score 2):

FTP on Azure only works with "passive mode".

Check out this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wats/archive/2013/12/13/setting-up-a-passive-ftp-server-in-windows-azure-vm.aspx and follow every step to set up passive mode.

You will also need to tell your FTP client to keep the connection alive so that it doesn't start a second connection while the first connection is still alive.  To set this in FileZilla client, go to Edit, Settings, Connection, FTP, and check "Send FTP keep-alive commands" checkbox.

Hope this helps!